# How to config nginx for i18n localize to serve app with langauge param?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I do have a angular application serving different languages e.g. `en` and `es`.

With the pervious angular versions `8.x`, I had following `nginx.conf` to serve the correct app based on the param language in the URL e.g. `https://my-app/es`, `https://my-app/en`:

```
...
include /usr/share/nginx/nginx.lang.conf;

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
       try_files $uri /myapp/$lang/index.html =404;
    }

    location /myapp/assets/(.*) {
       try_files /myapp/$lang/assets/$1 =404;
    }
}
```

and here is the part `nginx.lang.conf` where I set the lang:

```
map $http_accept_language $accept_lang {
  default insertDefaultLocale;
}

map $arg_locale $lang_param {
  default $accept_lang;
}

map $request_uri $lang {
  default $lang_param;
}
```

It did work as expected.

But now I did ugrade the app to version 10 and I use the following build command: `ng build --localize --output-path=dist --prod` which generates `/en`and `/es`folder under `/dist` to build the different langauges for the app.

Unfortunately I can't call the application with the specific languages e.g. `my-app/en` and/or `my-app/es`. It's a blank page as it deosn't get the correct path for the assets which should be e.g.: `/my-app/es/stylesxxxxx.css`, `/my-app/es/mainxxxxxxxx.js` etc. What I get is a path to assets which doesn't contian the language path. e.g. `/my-app/stylesxxxxx.css` `/my-app/mainxxxxxxxx.js`.

What it should I add and/or change the get the correct path to the assests and the specific app for specific language.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your configuration where you set `$lang`. What's going on here? Did you omit something relevant?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed to add a part which is including the extra file for lang config. I'll add it.

Comment: `location /myapp/assets/(.*) {` is missing a `~` operator - it should be something like: `location ~ ^/myapp/assets/(.*)$ {`

Comment: @RichardSmith: I'll give it a try.

Comment: @RichardSmith: I think it should be `~^/myapp/assets/(.*)$ {` without empty space, right?

Comment: [The documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) uses a space. It may be optional IDK.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work with space. I'll tryo nce again without space.

Comment: Both tries didn't fix the issue.